# Inner for loops won't follow outer for loop

Tags: python, json, list, loops

The outer loop scrapes several URLs based on marketid. Each URL contains information about a horse race. This information includes odds. I want to append the largest odds in each race. For example, I would want to append $101, if the odds of horses for a race were $2.5, $3.5, $10, $36, and $101. The problem I have is that when I append the odds to 'data', all of the odds for all of the URLs are appended. This means that it finds the max value for all of the races, instead of each race. If the inner loops followed the outer loop, this wouldn't happen.

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd 
startdate = datetime.date(2020, 0o1, 0o1)
enddate = datetime.date(2020, 0o1, 0o2)
daycount = (enddate - startdate).days
date = startdate
marketids = []
for i in range(daycount):
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    request1 = requests.get('https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/daily_racing_results?date='+str(date))
    json1 = request1.json()
    for market in json1:
        if market['raceType'] in ['R']:
            for id in market['markets']:
                marketids.append(market["markets"][0]["marketId"])
data = []
for marketid in marketids:
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/race_results/?market_id=1.{marketid}&nz_tote_event_id=',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json2 = request2.json()
    for runner in json2['runners']:
        for market in runner['markets']:
            if market.get('productType') == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP':
                data.append(market.get('price'))
                max = 0
                for d in data:
                    if d>max:
                        max = d
print(max)
```

Here is an example of the json:

```
"runners":[
   {
      "selectionId":"24369070",
      "runnerName":"Bloomin Crafty",
      "barrierNo":3,
      "saddleClothNo":1,
      "placedResult":2,
      "startingPosition":1,
      "trainerName":"Kathryn Durden",
      "jockeyName":"Jarrod Fry",
      "weight":58.0,
      "silkColor":"Hot Pink Royal Blue Horseshoe Hot Pink Royal Blue \u0026 White Checked Sleeves \u0026 Cap",
      "colorURL":"c20200713MURT/1364572.png",
      "bestTote":10.4,
      "markets":[
         {
            "productType":"WIN_ODDS_BSP",
            "price":10.09,
            "reductionFactor":8.33
         },
         {
            "productType":"PLACE_ODDS_BSP",
            "price":2.92,
            "reductionFactor":13.85
         }
      ],
      "bestNZTote":0
   }
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what might be wrong as the indentation is inconsistent in places due perhaps to cut and paste issues. Please fix that. Also, `max_price = max(data)` can replace that loop that is incorrectly indented.

Comment: what do you expect as output ??

Comment: A list of numbers. The current output produced by max only produces one number which is the max of the whole data set.

Comment: @onthepunt2 So your output should be a list containing maximum prices for each 'marketid' . Am I right?

Comment: `data.append(market.get('price'))` is going to append every single "market price" because you are iterating through `runners`, then `market`, and then appending the `market['price']` to `data`. And then, in each of those loops, you are recalculating the `max` based on what is in `data`. So by the time you reach the `max` calculation, you have all previous `market['price']` value in `data`. Also, you are not getting a "list" of max prices because you never create one to track it, you simply overwrite `max` with this line: `max = d`